# Pass a parameter to a Kentico Marketing Automation workflow

Tags: asp.net, kentico, kentico-12

How do I pass a parameter to a Marketing Automation workflow?

I need to pass a parameter called 'MeetingId' to the workflow 'MeetingInvitation'. How can I do that?

```
        ContactInfo contact = ContactInfoProvider.GetContacts()
                                                    .WhereEquals("ContactEmail", "chamara@e.com")
                                                    .TopN(1)
                                                    .FirstOrDefault();

        // Gets the marketing automation process
        WorkflowInfo process = WorkflowInfoProvider.GetWorkflowInfo("MeetingInvitation", WorkflowTypeEnum.Automation);

        if ((contact != null) && (process != null))
        {
            // Creates an automation manager instance
            AutomationManager manager = AutomationManager.GetInstance(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);
           
            // Starts the process for the contact
            manager.StartProcess(contact, process.WorkflowID);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can pass this as a parameter inside marketing automation process with a code like this. The only way you can pass something into MA process is through the trigger data if the trigger is set to activity. Please refer to [this blog article for example](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/working-with-forms-in-kentico-marketing-automation-part-2), basically it showcases how you can start MA process after form submission and get form submission data inside MA process.

You would need something similar I guess:

- configure your MA process to be run on activity type of a trigger
- in your code rather than starting the process explicitly, you can issue this type of activity for the contact, including your ID in ActivityDetailItemID parameter
- by this issued activity Kentico will start MA process automatically and inside this MA process you can access activity details with required data